# JavaScript validate various form elements

Tags: javascript

I have a script thats trying to validate some form elements but i cant figure out the correct syntax for each "if" I need, its doing absolutely nothing. I believe the issue may be that on the same form there are many "tabs" or other forms so I may have to write which form the element belongs to but I dont know the syntax for that, like if its 
var NewStatus = document.getElementById("ChangeStatusForm.CURRENT_STATUS").VALUE;
if none of the alerts apply then i just need it to submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateInfo()


var NewStatus = document.getElementById("CURRENT_STATUS").VALUE;
var OldStatus = document.getElementByID("ovpInfo.current_status").VALUE;
var CheckNumber = document.getElementByID("check_number").VALUE;
var CheckDate = document.getElementByID("check_date").VALUE;


if (NewStatus == 0){
alert ("Please select a New Status");
    }
 else if (NewStatus == 5){
alert ("This claim has already been collected");
    } else if (NewStatus == 10){
alert ("This claim has already been collected");
    } else if (NewStatus == 10 and CheckNumber =="" or CheckDate == ""){
alert ("Please enter Payment Details");
    else
document.forms['ChangeStatusForm'].submit() ;
    }




</script>
```

In order to just get at least one variable check working ive edited my script. this does not work either though (used some syntax I found to specify the actual form the element belongs to)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateInfo()
{

var NewStatus = document.forms["ChangeStatusForm"]["CURRENT_STATUS"].value;


if (NewStatus == 0){
alert ("Please select a New Status");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing some curly brackets a few places. First of all the code should be wrapped in the function like this: `function ValidateInfo() { ... code goes here... }`. Second, on both sides of you last `else` statement. The way you've done it now, the `else` statement is wrapped inside your last `else if`statement. Try and fix that first.

Comment: Oh, and writing `and` and `or` in an if statement is not quite right. It's `&&` and `||`, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, and it's `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`. Notice the lower case "d". You also want to get the `.value` not the `.VALUE`.

Comment: Javascript syntax in always case-sensitive. For instance, This includes methods, properties, functions, variables and field names. The three elements that you run document.getElementById should have id's in exactly the same case as you entered them. It's for this reason that it's handy to have a casing style, or just always do IDs in one case so that that never gets in the way of your script.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong expression for "document.getElementById("id")" and you need to change the or, and for "&&", "||".

And I using a flag for return the correct value.

for example:

```
  function ValidateInfo()

 var flag = true;
 var NewStatus = document.getElementById("CURRENT_STATUS").value;
 var OldStatus = document.getElementByID("ovpInfo.current_status").value;
 var CheckNumber = document.getElementByID("check_number").value;
 var CheckDate = document.getElementByID("check_date").value;


 if (NewStatus == 0){
  alert ("Please select a New Status");
  flag=false;
 }
 else if (NewStatus == 5){
 alert ("This claim has already been collected");
    flag=false;
  } else if (NewStatus == 10){
  alert ("This claim has already been collected");
     flag=false;
    } else if (NewStatus == 10 and CheckNumber =="" or CheckDate == ""){
    alert ("Please enter Payment Details");
       flag=false;


      }else{
        flag=true; 
            }
     if( flag ){document.forms['ChangeStatusForm'].submit()}
```

good luck

Comment: Ok I see were most of my problem lies. the object im suppose to compare to is an option from a select box. How can I get its value?

Comment: For a select option you need in this way:

x = document.getElementById('your iD');// select id

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
     if(x.options[i].selected == true){
       var selectedOption = x.options[i].value;
       }
  }
In This way you can access to de value.
regards.